# How change UnauthorizedHttpException errorHandler auth.basic in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication

I'm trying to make api with basic auth in Laravel 5.5.48

When auth is success ('username' and 'password') response is correct, but if auth is unsuccess(wrong 'username' and 'password' data) displays error
[image]

What I haven't tried, but I couldn't change Exception displays on my response (response()->json(['status'=>'auth failed']))

routes/api.php

```
Route::post('/index', 'Api\MyController@index')->middleware('auth.basic');
```

app/Http/Controllers/Api/MyController@index

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json(array('status' => 'success'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Exception handler`:

Within `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
        return response()->json(['status'=>'auth failed'], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

> Don't forget to use `UnauthorizedException` and `Response`:
>
> ```php
> use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException
> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
> ```

Check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/errors#the-exception-handler) for more details about the Laravel Exception Handler.

Hope it helps.